# Spring @Transactional(readOnly=true) revert the properties?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactional

Just a simple Question with a Car-entity persisted field color of value red:

```
00  @Transactional public class MyBean{...
01    public void test(){
02        Car c = s.find(Car.class,1);
03        c.setColor("blue");
04        test1(c);
05        System.out.println(c.getColor());   
06    }
07    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
08    public void test1(Car c){
09        c.setName("black");
10    }
11  }
```

Assuming, we are in Spring ORM TX-Transactional-Annotation environment, with transactional semantics and transaction scoped persistence context.

What will be printed to Console?

- red
- blue
- black

Comment: Peter, could you please provide the required information about aspect weaving and transaction propagation. Are you using load time or compile time weaving? What kind of transaction propagation did you configure? I think this will help us to give a clear answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming transactional semantics are enabled when calling methods of the same instance and NESTED transaction propagation:
It depends on the scope of the persistence context.

Assuming a transaction scoped persistence context:
`black` is printed to the console. The car instance is detached, because it was fetched outside the readonly transaction and is not merged into the readonly transaction. Calling the setter on a detached instance is safe (like the call to `setColor("blue")`.

Assuming an extended scope of the persistence context:
`black` is also printed. From the javadoc of `@Transactional`

If

> A transaction manager which cannot interpret the read-only hint will not throw an exception when asked for a read-only transaction.

And from the JPA 2.0 Spec Section 2.4.1.2 Mapping of Derived Identities:

> The embedded id attributes that correspond
>   to the relationship are treated by the provider as “read only”—that is, any updates to them on
>   the part of the application are not propagated to the database.

But I'm not 100% sure, if there isn't an exception thrown. Since the color property isn't an embedded id the behaviour may vary.

If transactional semantics are available via proxies then see the [answer of Adrian Shum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12816801/1466267)

Comment: I forgot to tell: another @Transaction is on class-scope readonly=false, so the s points to the available hibernate-session.
So anyway it returns black, alright. 
Is there any way to get Red or Blue instead without refresh it manuality?

Comment: You could use the memento pattern for that. But I really think you should get rid of the persistent entity modifications within the read only transaction.

Comment: In fact, the way OP is using Spring Transaction and Hibernate is unreasonable.  There is nothing to do with the scope in fact.  Please read my answer. :)

Comment: Im irritated now, i never call em.persist(c);, does it happens automatically on line 06?

Comment: @PeterRader the entity manager knows about `c`, because I assume that during the call to `s.find(Car.class,1)` the returned car is put into the current persistence context and hence `c` is managed. On committing a transaction the managed entities are automatically synchronized with the database.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have falled into a trap in AOP in Spring.

Transaction in Spring is achieved by AOP, and AOP in Spring is achieved by having proxy around the actual target.

You have annotated @Transactional for MyBean.  Assume someone else is calling instance of `MyBean.test()`, it is in fact not "talking" to that object directly.  There is a proxy which looks exactly like `MyBean`, but it create the transaction, then invoke the actual `MyBean.test()`, and afterwards, commit/rollback.

It is something like this:

```
         test()                     test()
[Caller] ------->  [MyBean Proxy]  ------> [MyBean]
```

However, when you are invoking `test1()` in `test()`, that actually means `this.test1()`, which means you are invoking the MyBean instance directly:

```
          [MyBean Proxy]     [MyBean] <--
                                |       |  test1(c)
                                ---------
```

Without going through the `MyBean Proxy` (which is responsible to do the transaction trick), your invocation to `test1()` in fact have nothing to do with Transaction.  It is just a plain method.

So you know the answer.

Moreover, even you manage to invoke through the proxy, it is not going to change the story:

```
          -> [MyBean Proxy]     [MyBean]
test1(c) |                         |
          -------------------------
```

That's because the instance of `Car` you passed to `test1()` is retrieved in the transaction (that means, Hibernate session) around `test()`, and whatever you change in `test1()`, you are not doing anything with the Hibernate session you created separately in `test1()` (if you use REQUIRED_NEW propagation).  You are simply changing the state of the object passed in.  Therefore, calling `test1(c)` is still nothing but a plain method call.

Comment: `@Transactional` can also be used with compile-time-weaving. When this is the case there is no need for proxies and also method calls on the same instance will enable transactional semantics.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker That's true, I should mention that though I believe LTW is more widely used.  However, even for CTW, my second point still holds  :)

Comment: You are right, my assumption is NESTED propagation, which is kind of a natural assumption for me, but very rarely used in practice. So we still end up with `black`in all cases mentioned so far.

Comment: My @PersistenceContext is pointed to HibernateEntityManager hem; So s=hem.getSession(); Trust in me, the environmet setup is ok.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Please look in detail in my second point.  It is not about NESTED propagation I believe.  No matter what kind of propagation it is, there is no difference.  The car passed in has nothing to do with the inner transaction around test1().  Transaction around test1() have no effect on that car instance.

Comment: @PeterRader We are not criticizing whether your persistence context is correct or not.  First, are you using Load Time Weaving or Compile Time Weaving? for the more common LTW, you gotta understand how the proxy stuff work (my first example), and for both LTW and CTW, if you pass an entity and modify its content in another "transaction", without special handling (I doubt if there is any way to make it work though), the em in the inner transaction will know nothing about the passed-in entity, and hence, your change to entity has nothing to do with in the inner transaction.

Comment: @AdrianShum There is still a point about NESTED propagation I don't get. Suppose there are changes in the inner transaction that the entity manager of the inner transaction knows about. Upon commiting the inner transaction, how can the database state be correctly synchronized, if the outer transaction isn't synchronized at all before committing or even starting the inner?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker you have raised a key point: "if the em of inner tx knows".  If entity A is retrieved in a outer tx, it is "bound" to the em/session of that tx.  If we have a nested tx, this is obviously another tx, and the inner em should not have any knowledge about the A (to be honest I haven't tried on that and I just believe that's the way Hibernate handle nested transaction).  Unless you attached A to the inner em/session (which I don't believe it is possible as it is attached with an active outer session), there is no way to have the inner em take effect on change of the A passed in

Comment: btw I think we are guessing too much on what can be happened.  In OP, it is simply a @Transaction which implies REQUIRED propagation, that means, no matter the tx around test1() is valid or not, it is still running in the same tx around test(), and test1() is acting as a plain method and nothing more.  The tx declaration around test1() is not going to have any effect.